# Trying to Add a Separator in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling, compilation-error

I would like to add a line segment of specified length in the Table of Contents to separate two distinct portions. (I have search this site, but could only find an example to add a full-length horizontal line.)

I am surprised at my difficulty in accomplishing this because \rule{1.25in}{.15mm} works fine within the document itself. However, when I try to add the following, I get an error message:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{\rule{1.25in}{.15mm}}
```

Consider the working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 12pt} %set space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Section in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Subsection in the Table of Contents


% Centering Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}


\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 3}


\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{\rule{1.25in}{.15mm}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Next Part of the Table of Contents}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

However, when I run the code with the \addcontentsline{toc}{\rule{1.25in}{.15mm}} command, I get the error message "Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. \addtocontents".

And the following output results:

[image]

Again, I would like to add a horizontal line segment of specified length to the TOC---but everything I've tried so far has failed. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong and how to correct it? Thank you.

Comment: \addcontentsline has three argument.  You should use \addtocontents, or add {chapter} or {section}, etc.

Comment: @John Kormylo But wouldn't a page number be displayed? If so, how may I suppress the unwanted page number? Thank you,

Comment: @John Kormylo I just tried to specify {chapter}, but I get a different error message. It seems that the TOC does not accept the way I've defined the line segment, though it works fine in the document.

Comment: I didn't realize how badly tocloft was messing with `\l@chapter`.  Anyway, if you don't want the page number, use `\addtocontents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\addtocontents` rather than `\addcontentsline` and insert a `\par` after your `\rule` in order for the ToC contents to be processed successfully.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{12pt}%set space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{8pt}  %set space after each Section in the Table of Contents
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{8pt}  %set space after each Subsection in the Table of Contents

% Centering Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tocloftpagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 3}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\rule[.1\normalbaselineskip]{1.25in}{.15mm}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-\cftbeforechapskip}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

I moved the `\rule` up a tad to appear better vertically centered between the two chapter headings. I also used the default [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) vertical spacing/skips and page styles rather than add that content to the ToC manually. It doesn't really matter that much though.

Comment: Thank you. It should work perfectly, but I the line "\addtocontents{toc}{\rule[.1\normalbaselineskip]{1.25in}{.15mm}\par}" is causing a problem on my end. The problem must be with me. I recently downloaded the most recent version of TexStudio to replace my old version, and have since had problems with, for example, some centering code in Tcolorbox. This might explain why I am not able to execute properly the two good answers that have been posted. Thank you again. I must figure out what's wrong on my end.

Comment: @mlchristians: Delete the `.aux` and `.toc` and try again. Some auxiliary files could get corrupted, or linger with faulty code in them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; unfortunately, it did not work for this problem. But I hope I remember for the future. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though it didn't work for me because of a problem on my end, I did discover that  \addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{2in}{\underline{\hspace{2in}}}\par} does the trick. Thanks also for telling me about the \par. It doesn't work otherwise. Thanks also for your comment about .aux and .toc. I believe that is why I got the revised code to work on a second run after it abended on the first.

Answer (score 3):

This will place the line precisely in the middle of a 36pt gap (`\baselineskip=12pt`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 12pt} %set space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Section in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Subsection in the Table of Contents


% Centering Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}


\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 3}

\addtocontents{toc}{\rule[\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox]{1.25in}{.15mm}\vskip 12pt}

\addtocontents{toc}{Next Part of the Table of Contents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no doubt it works on your end; but for some reason, when I run it, I get the error message `` Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 22.''

Comment: Beats the heck out of me.  Try removing the optional argument of \rule.  it could be computed separately.

Comment: The problem has to be on my end. The other day I downloaded the most recent version of TexStudio and have noticed here and there, for example, with the \tcolorbox package, I am not able to do some of the things I should be able to. The download was very quick. Perhaps there was something else I omitted to do. In any case, I've got to figure out the problem on my end. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @mlchristians there is no way texstudio is causing issues on its own it is just an editor calling latex. Are you by any chance on Linux/macports and now you have two latex installations because installing texstudio brought texlive with it as a recommended install

Comment: @daleif When I downloaded the most recent version of Texstudio, I thought  I would be receiving all the files in the ``TeX Collection'' as well. Since the download was very rapid, and I seem to be as limited as I was before with my old Tex Collection, I suspect I got no updated files, only the Editor. Perhaps I need to join TUG to be sure I get all the file and package updates on a DVD. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @mlchristians whose things are not related at all. By design you can use any editor you want with latex, it only calls latex that's all. It us kinda like when users ask on the site how to install a certain package using texmaker (another editor), you don't. Installing latex packages are either don't via the package manager that are a part of your latex installation, or on some Linux via the Linux dist. The editor is not related at all