# Table of contents with horizontal lines like table

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, minitoc, tocstyle

In my thesis, I have to change the table of contents layout according to the following picture. Being not so skilled in latex I can't get a way out. The codes of different people at StackExchange are very difficult for me to understand.
[image]

Comment: You will first need to remove `\contentsname` from the defualt display. `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` can be used to add lines and text.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568586/trying-to-add-a-separator-in-the-table-of-contents for example.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't help me to get the desired TOC. I want a horizontal rule before the title of the table of contents.

Comment: Yeah, it would probably be easier to modify \tableofcontents directly.  Also, you need to decide whether or not to use a package like titlesec.  (Personally, I avoid them, as they complicate the code.)  Note that the individual entriies are non standard as well.